# Refresh page and close browser callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular

I am new to Angular, I am developing Angular 6 application. I have used callback which called when we refresh and close page:

```
 @HostListener("window:beforeunload", ["$event"]) unloadHandler(event: Event) {
            console.log("Processing beforeunload...");
            event.returnValue = true;
          }
```

But Now my requirement is, when we close browser then i should sign out. And i have implemented this in above code sample(Removing token from local storage).

But problem is when i refresh page this callback called and it removes token.

Is there other way to handle these two conditions using other callback??

Thanks in advance

Comment: There is no callback event for closing a browser.

Comment: Take a look at using sessionStorage for token instead of localStorage

Answer (score 0):

Try Storing the token as a cookie without specifying a date,then the cookie is removed once the user quits his or her browser.So when he or she open the browser token will be no longer available and will be redirect to sign in.Hope this helps.